# receiving selected choice on Tkinter listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I'm trying to build a listbox using Tkinter and receive the selected option by clicking it.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
lst=Listbox(root, height=30, width=50)
lst.insert(1, "hy")
lst.insert(2, "hello")
lst.insert(3, "hey")
lst.pack()

sel = lst.curselection()
print sel

root.mainloop()
```

However, when I run the code it prints me an empty tuple before I pressed any choise.
Does someone know how to get the selected choise after I press one and not right after I run it?
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the reason you are getting an empty tuple is because you have executed the statements:

```
sel = lst.curselection()
print(sel)
```

before you have executed the `root.mainloop()`

Secondly, your setup for listbox fails to include a `StringVar` variable to hold your list.
Once the variable has been defined, you should be able to use the .insert statements to add your list items one at a time, or you can initialize the `StringVar` variable using a .set('hy', 'hello', 'hey') command.

To provide a return of a selected variable, you must incorporate an event handler to determine the list position selected onclick or some other triggering method.

For a pretty clear explanation of these characteristics check [here](http://reu.cct.lsu.edu/documents/Python_Course/tkinter.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the selection about a millisecond after creating the widget, well before the user has a chance to see the UI much less interact with it.

GUI programs are *event based*, meaning that things happen in response to events. Events are things like clicking buttons, inserting data into input widgets, and selecting items from listboxes.

You need to do one of two things: create a button or other widget which will get the selected item, or configure it so that a function is called whenever an item is selected.

No matter which solution you use, you will need a function that ultimately calls the `curselection` method of the listbox to get a list of indices. You can then call the `get` method to get the selected item or items.

Here's a function definition that will print the selected item, or print "no selection" if nothing is selected. So that it can be resused without modification. we'll define it to take the listbox as an argument.

Note: this example assumes the widget only supports a single select, to keep it simple:

```
def print_selection(listbox):
    selection = listbox.curselection()
    if selection:
        print(f"selected item: {listbox.get(selection[0])}")
    else:
        print("nothing is selected")
```

### Using a button

To call this from a button is straight-forward. We just create a button after we create the listbox, and use the `command` attribute to call the function. Since the function we wrote earlier needs a parameter, we'll use `lambda` to create a temporary function for the button.

```
button = tk.Button(root, text="Print Selected Item", command=lambda: print_selection(lst))
button.pack()
```

### Calling the function when the selection is made

To call the function whenever the user changes the selection, we can bind a function to the `<<ListboxSelect>>` event. We'll create a separate function for this, and then pull the widget from the event object that is automatically passed to the function.

```
def print_callback(event):
    print_selection(event.widget)

lst.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", print_callback)
```